# Reinstall package that was not from repo from ubuntu repository

Tags: package-management

I've added ppa repository with some package(s) with versions greater that versions in official ubuntu repository. After that I upgraded (`sudo apt-get install upgrade`), then I delete ppa.

Now I want to delete this packages and reinstall versions from officialrepo. How do I do that? I don't want delete package that depends on these ones.

Ubuntu version is 13.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can downgrade with the package version:

```
apt-cache policy ubuntu-sdk
ubuntu-sdk:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.004
  Version table:
     1.009~sdkppa~raring1~test6 0
        200 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa/ubuntu/ raring/main amd64 Packages
     1.004 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/universe amd64 Packages

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk=1.004
```

(Just change `ubuntu-sdk` with the name of the package)

To do several at once, you can use aptitude for the task (this part is assuming you removed the PPA's, will not work in other cases)

```
aptitude search '?version(CURRENT)!?origin(ubuntu)'
```

This will show you a list of packages that are not installed from the repositories and are installed, you can downgrade them using `aptitude -t saucy install package`. Of course if the package is not available in the official repositories the best is remove them.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the PPA again, and to disable it AND revert any package it installed to the default version in Ubuntu repository you will nedd ppa-purge and use the command:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge

sudo ppa-purge PPA-name
```

For more information, see http://www.webupd8.org/2009/12/remove-ppa-repositories-via-command.html